# c# : string length without predefined function

Tags: c#

I am writing a code to find out the total length of string in c#.
code is as follow

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "Amit Kumar";
            int c = 0;
            for(int i = 0; str[i]!="\n"; i++)
            {

                c++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

but it showing **!=** operator can not be applied to operands on char or string type.
can you solve my problem

Comment: The problem is you mean to be doing the char '\n', and not the string "\n". Also str.Length works too.

Comment: I don't want to use any predefined function.(already mention in my title )

Comment: string.Length is not a function

Comment: characters are represented with single quotes in c#.  try str[i] != '\n'

Comment: Just to give you an advice, strings are not terminated by the `\n` character

Comment: I don't think your loop will ever end.  There's no new line character in "Amit Kumar".

Comment: Just so you're aware, even if you were doing the comparison correctly, your loop would crash. Your string doesn't contain a '\n' character, so `i` will continue to increment until it's larger than your string's length. The `str[i]` check will then cause an IndexOutOfRangeException. C# strings don't have any particular termination character. Your best option is a foreach loop, if you don't want to rely on str.Length. @Trent, the loop will crash when i  is out of bounds of the string.

Comment: The *right* answer is using `String.Length`. I'm guessing this "no predefined function" requirement is because this is schoolwork; in this case - and I don't mean to be rude - you'd better try to find the answers by yourself rather than asking for the solution on SO.

Comment: @CurtisRutland - I agree. It will crash... not loop forever. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare a string to a char using `!=` as stated in the error. So use `'\n'` instead. But anyways, your string doesn't contain the newline character and would never terminate.

We can make your code work with some modifications. Use `foreach` to loop over the characters in the string.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "Amit Kumar";
            int c = 0;
            foreach(char x in str)
            {
                c++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I hope this is just for education, as there's [built in functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) to tell you the length of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need this code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "Amit Kumar";
            int c = 0;
            foreach(char x in str)
            {
                if (str[i] != '\n')
                  c++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[*mason*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23302156/1715579) is perfectly fine, but here's an alternative:

```
void Main()
{
    string str = "Amit Kumar";
    int c = 0;
    while(str != "")
    {
        str = str.Substring(1);
        c++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This method successively removes characters until it's left with the empty string, then prints the number of characters removed. But just for fun, this can be rewritten as

```
void Main()
{
    string str = "Amit Kumar";
    int c = 0;
    while(str.Substring(++c) != "") /* do nothing */;
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```